# Customise PHP code using remote user

Tags: php, client

I am trying to give users a page depending on the windows login used. The crucial point is definitely not security, instead people want it comfortable, so they open the browser and see what they are meant to see. I thought of $_server['remote_user'] but this is empty. I googled a lot and found only things which seem to need authentication or sessions, both requiring many hours of work ;)

I am using WAMP and do not want to be more specific on the system because I want it to run tomorrow as well and I prefer the dirty solution to nothing. Grateful for your comments.

bj

Comment: will users be accessing it via 'localhost' ?

Comment: You'd need to use NTLM authentication, in that case, because browsers will NOT transmit windows logins by default. IE used to do that in the very early days, but hasn't for a LONG time.

Comment: @kevin B. what the ### is NTLM authentication? (may be stupid)

Comment: You will probably have to div into some ActiveX...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your comments I have found a viable solution at least for this special purpose:

The first file reads windows username using WScript.Network and sends a form containing the username. The second writes it to a session var. Dark and dirty but easy to maintain and handle...

File 1, session02.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

<form id="form_user_name" name="form_new_record" action="session03.php" method="post" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <input name="user_name" type="text" >
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script type=text/javascript>
    var wscript_network=new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");
    var user_name=wscript_network.UserName;
    form_user_name.user_name.value=user_name;
    form_user_name.submit();
</script>
```

File2, session03.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $current_windows_user=$_POST['user_name'];
    $_SESSION['current_windows_user'] = $current_windows_user;
    echo "---".$_SESSION['current_windows_user']
?>
```

Later either $_SESSION['current_windows_user'] or $current_windows_user are available

Thanks to everybody!

Answer (score -1):

Your question is a bit unclear, if you are asking to use PHP to check a users login from a Windows PC, this can not be done.

However, if you are wanting to use a simple (little security) HTML form along with PHP and MySQL (both included with *AMP) I would suggest doing the following:

On your index.html page:

```
<form method="POST" action="validatelogin.php">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter username" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

On your validatelogin.php page

```
session_start();
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=example;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn,'root','password', $opt);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username");
    $username = $_POST['username'];
$stmt->execute(array(
                                ':username'=>$username,
                                ));
$exist = $stmt->fetch();
if (!empty($exist)) {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $exist["id"];
}
```

The last step is the most crucial:

This setup assumes you have a database named example, using the login credentails of username:root password:password.  This example also assumes you have a table created inside of that database named users.

That table will have the following setup:

2 rows

first row name: id

first row type: int

first row A_I: checked

second row name: username

second row type: text

From here you can insert into the database usernames that you want people to use, I hope this helped.

Comment: that gave me a good hint, will try it. Sry I dont have the rep to vote up yet.